# ¿Como mostrar el nombre de usuario existente en una base de datos con jQuery AJAX?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, base-de-datos

Se pudiera decir que soy "nuevo" en esto del lenguaje php y las consultas mysql, puesto que estóy elaborando un sitio web, prácticamente Red Social, que se centraliza en alojamiento de fotos por usuarios, es decir, cada usuario registrado tiene la oportunidad de subir sus fotos, crear albumes, etc.
Digo esto por si la manera en la que intento hacer estas funciones para esta pagina no son las adecuadas o no son las mas recomendables y me lo puedan hacer saber, ya que el problema como tal que tengo es que nosé como hacer que con jQuery y AJAX pueda mostrar el nombre de usuario recién registrado y logueado también.

En este caso solo estoy usando el area de registro que cuando el usuario se registre, acceda a esta área del login, pero he intentado con ciertas consultas de php , pero eso implicaría que tuviese que colocar el codigo php en la misma pagina del login para que al recargar, esa variable con su nombre esté definida, ya que si lo hago desde un archivo externo de php, al insertar esa variable en la pagina del login me dirá que está indefinida, por ende decidí usar jQuery y AJAX para esto, el codigo con el que estoy tratando de hacerlo es un ejemplo, una proyecto de prueba, porque no me gusta experimentar en mi proyecto como tal...

```js
var usuario = $('#user');
var envio = $('#send');

envio.click(function(e){
 if (usuario.val()[0] !== '@') {
  e.preventDefault();
 alert("El nombre de usuario siempre empieza con '@'");
 }
 else{
  nUser = usuario.val();
  $.ajax({
   url:'Mostrar.php',
   data:{nUser},
   type:'POST',
   success: function(response){
    var tarea = JSON.parse(response);

    tarea.forEach(tarea =>{
     console.log(task);
    })
   }
  })
 }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola como estas? si buscas hacerlo en una misma pagina, esta mal. Lo que recomendaría es enviarle una alerta como sweet alert al usuario que se registro y mostrarle el nombre de usuario en la alerta. Si lo que buscas es que un usuario recien registrado sea redirigido a la pantalla de login con el usuario ya registrado por AJAX no es posible, dado a que ésta api solo trabaja en tiempo real y en el mismo archivo PHP.

Otra recomendación es guardar el nombre de usuario recien registrado en SESSION y cuando carga el login aplicarselo al input de nombre de usuario y luego destruir la SESSION.

Comment: Hola amigo, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, aunque no lo creas, dijistes algo clave que son lo de las sesiones, lo cual no tenía conocimiento de eso, pues acabo de investigar acerca de ello, y logré hacerlo, ya veo que es mucho mas fácil, e incluso no tuve la necesidad de insertar mi código php en la misma página de login.

En otras palabras ya está resuelto mi problema. :)

¿Como cierro el post? xd

Comment: Buenisimo solo tenes que poner el check que dice que solucioné el problema a la izquierda de la respuesta. Exitos y un placer ayudar!